# bad Itemize environment with babel and StandardItemLabels

Tags: babel, french

Using the StandardItemLabels options of babel, itemize bullets are in the margins. How is it possible to set up properly bullet item and right spacing ?

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
    \item une
    \item liste
    \item de 
    \item mots
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item et un
    \item et deux
    \item et trois
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
    \item[obj] def
    \item[obj] def
    \item[obj] def
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: with StandardItemLabels option]
[image: without StandardItemLabels options]

I would like only change the bullet not the position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section 3.3 of the [documentation for `frenchb`](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb-doc.pdf).

In your case you might want to use `\frenchbsetup{ItemLabels=\textbullet}` rather than `\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}` so as to only change the label, not the spacing.

Otherwise change `\listindentFB` and `\labelwidthFB` to fit you need - see the aforementioned doc for examples.